# Sorting a NSSet of NSManagedObjects by attribute

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, core-data

Given an `NSSet` that contains objects that are a subclass `NSManagedObject` with a string attribute called `name`, how can I sort the set by name?  Is this where I would use an `NSPredicate`?

Thank you!

Comment: correct me if I'm wrong, but I believe `NSSet` is unordered, meaning the elements contained are in no particular order (conceptually speaking), meaning that a `NSSet` can't be sorted. You can put the objects in an `NSArray`, which is ordered and can be sorted.

Comment: Sounds like this is what the OP is asking...

Answer (score 33, accepted):

No, but you'd use an `NSSortDescriptor`.

You'd use the `sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:` method like this:

```
NSSortDescriptor *nameDescriptor = [NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"name" ascending:YES];
NSArray *sorted = [yourSet sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:[NSArray arrayWithObject:nameDescriptor]];
```

Comment: Thanks! Would these need to be released for memory management?

Comment: @Bill The `sorted` array is autoreleased, so no.

Comment: and if I create NSSet from sorted NSArray by NSSet(array: <#[AnyObject]#>)), will it keep order?

Answer (score 5):

By mentioning NSPredicate, I feel as though the OP wanted to sort the set as part of the executed fetch. Whether he meant this or not, here is an example of this. Say you have a to-many inverse relationship between an Employee entity and a Department entity i.e. a department contains many employees. Given you've fetched the department already, fetch the employees in the department and sort them by first name:

Using MagicalRecord:

```
Department *department = someFetchedDepartment; 
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"department == %@", department];
NSArray *sortedEmployees = [Employee MR_findAllSortedBy:@"firstName" ascending:YES withPredicate:predicate];
```

Without MagicalRecord:

```
NSFetchRequest *request = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];    

NSEntityDescription *employeeEntity = [NSEntityDescription @"Employee" inManagedObjectContext:self.context];
[request setEntity:employeeEntity];

Department *department = someFetchedDepartment; 
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"department == %@", department];
[request setPredicate:predicate];

NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"firstName" ascending:ascending];
[request setSortDescriptors:@[sortDescriptor]];

NSError *error = nil;
NSArray *sortedEmployees = [self.context executeFetchRequest:request error:&error];
```

Comment: MagicalRecord: https://github.com/magicalpanda/MagicalRecord. OP really should have pointed this out as a third party solution.